# Selinux is blocking my external kernel module

Tags: fedora, kernel-modules, selinux

I'm trying to insert an external kernel module in permanent mode. During the boot, my module is being loaded by `systemd-modules-load` service so long as `Selinux` is permissive. But I want to keep Enforcing mode. I wasn't able to insert my module into `Selinux` list with `semodule` command. What else could I do? This is my environment:

```
Fedora release 27
Kernel version 4.18.19-100.fc27.x86_64
```

**rpm -qa 'selinux-*' output:**

```
selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-284.37.fc27.noarch
selinux-policy-3.13.1-284.37.fc27.noarch
```

**sestatus output:**

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

**systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service output:**

```
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-12-14 09:50:42 CET; 19min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 4397 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4397 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

dic 14 09:50:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
dic 14 09:50:42 localhost.localdomain systemd-modules-load[4397]: Failed to insert 'hello': Permission denied
dic 14 09:50:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
dic 14 09:50:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
dic 14 09:50:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
dic 14 09:50:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**ls -lZ /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load output:**

```
 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root system_u:object_r:systemd_modules_load_exec_t:s0 15576  4 mag  2018 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load
```

---

**/var/log/audit/audit.log**

```
type=SELINUX_ERR msg=audit(1533716850.521:304): op=security_bounded_transition seresult=denied oldcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 newcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:thumb_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
type=SELINUX_ERR msg=audit(1533716850.596:305): op=security_bounded_transition seresult=denied oldcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 newcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:thumb_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
type=SELINUX_ERR msg=audit(1533716851.081:306): op=security_bounded_transition seresult=denied oldcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 newcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:thumb_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
type=SELINUX_ERR msg=audit(1533716851.422:307): op=security_bounded_transition seresult=denied oldcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 newcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:thumb_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
..
type=SELINUX_ERR msg=audit(1533717134.510:310): op=security_bounded_transition seresult=denied oldcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 newcontext=system_u:system_r:fprintd_t:s0
```

---

**journalctl -xeb -u systemd-modules-load.service**

```
L'unità systemd-modules-load.service ha iniziato la fase di avvio.
dic 13 16:38:08 localhost.localdomain systemd-modules-load[14937]: Failed to insert 'hello': Permission denied
dic 13 16:38:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
dic 13 16:38:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules. -- Subject: L'unità systemd-modules-load.service è fallita
```

**ls -Z**

```
    system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 bls.conf             unconfined_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.devname
    system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 build                    system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.drm
    system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 config                   system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.modesetting
    system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 extra                    system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.networking
unconfined_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 hello.ko                 system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.order
    system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 kernel               unconfined_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.softdep
unconfined_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.alias        unconfined_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.symbols
unconfined_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.alias.bin    unconfined_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.symbols.bin
    system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.block            system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 source
    system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.builtin          system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 System.map
unconfined_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.builtin.bin      system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 updates
unconfined_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.dep              system_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 vdso
unconfined_u:object_r:modules_object_t:s0 modules.dep.bin                     system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 vmlinuz
```

**My module is in**

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Do you have a related AVC message in audit log `/var/log/audit/audit.log`?

Comment: Did you check audit log?

Comment: Where is the module located and what are the selinux context of the file ? `ls -Z` ? You may simply need to restore the context with restorecon see https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-65817443e1aad7a1d1c87f6a4dc73a964b38224b

Comment: Can you please use a pastebin for long output? At least use the code boxes, but pastebin is easier

Comment: Try running restorecon your module is unconfined_u

Comment: It seems to me din't work. I did so "restorecon -Rv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)" But the "systemctl restart systemd-modules-load" failed once again. Permission denied

Comment: Fedora 27 has reached end of life. Please update to a currently supported Fedora release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! After building the kernel module, I put it into directory `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net`. And then with the command `depmod` I resolved this issue. Now it's loaded after every boot.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not ideal from a security point of view... But you can try to work around this while maintaining `Enforcing` mode by allowing any domains to load kernel modules, by tweaking this SELinux boolean:

```
$ sudo semanage boolean --list | grep domain_kernel_load_modules
domain_kernel_load_modules     (off  ,  off)  Allow all domains to have the kernel load modules
```

You can tweak it with:

```
$ sudo semanage boolean --modify --on domain_kernel_load_modules
```

This operation actually modifies the compiled SELinux policy, so once you execute that command, it's permanent (no need to execute it again in further reboots.)

Comment: Probably consider that if restorecon fails

Comment: It didn't work neither "restorecon" nor "semage"

Comment: @MassimilianoD Please post more details of your environment... What version of Fedora? `rpm -qa 'selinux-*'` for the versions of the policies? What is the output of `systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service`? What about `ls -lZ /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load`, is the binary tagged with `systemd_modules_load_exec_t` SELinux type? Please update your question with the response to these questions.